# AppleScript read data every few minutes

Tags: applescript, handle, idle-timer

I run a screen which display some data on the menu bar

the variables are taken from "~/Desktop/_MyData.plist"

everything work fine, however when the data change on _MyData.plist

How, can I make the script getting the new data ? I guess we can't expect AppleScript to detect file change and then run the script but is there a way to get the plist data on idle maybe and keeping running the whole script.

Here is the part that only getting the data :

```
property theAccountNumberFromPlist : ""
property SNNumber : ""
property appName : ""
property devicesID : ""
property domainEMAIL : ""
property fullEmail : ""
property purchaseDate : ""
property thename : ""
property theList : ""

set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/_MyData.plist.plist"
tell application "System Events"
    set p_list to property list file (plistfile_path)
    -- read the plist data

set theAccountNumberFromPlist to value of property list item "AccountNumber" of p_list as text
set SNNumber to value of property list item "SNNUMBER" of p_list as text
set appName to value of property list item "appName" of p_list as text
set devicesID to value of property list item "devicesID" of p_list as text
set domainEMAIL to value of property list item "domainEMAIL" of p_list as text
set fullEmail to value of property list item "fullEmail" of p_list as text
set purchaseDate to value of property list item "purchaseDate" of p_list as text
set thename to value of property list item "thename" of p_list as text
```

end tell

Here is the whole script :

```
  use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
use framework "AppKit"

property StatusItem : missing value
property selectedMenu : ""
property theDisplay : ""
property defaults : class "NSUserDefaults"
property internalMenuItem : class "NSMenuItem"
property externalMenuItem : class "NSMenuItem"
property newMenu : class "NSMenu"
property theAccountNumberFromPlist : ""
property SNNumber : ""
property appName : ""
property devicesID : ""
property domainEMAIL : ""
property fullEmail : ""
property purchaseDate : ""
property thename : ""
property theList : ""




set the plistfile_path to "~/Desktop/_MyData.plist.plist"
tell application "System Events"
    set p_list to property list file (plistfile_path)
    -- read the plist data

    set theAccountNumberFromPlist to value of property list item "AccountNumber" of p_list as text
    set SNNumber to value of property list item "SNNUMBER" of p_list as text
    set appName to value of property list item "appName" of p_list as text
    set devicesID to value of property list item "devicesID" of p_list as text
    set domainEMAIL to value of property list item "domainEMAIL" of p_list as text
    set fullEmail to value of property list item "fullEmail" of p_list as text
    set purchaseDate to value of property list item "purchaseDate" of p_list as text
    set thename to value of property list item "thename" of p_list as text
end tell
if not (current application's NSThread's isMainThread()) as boolean then
    display alert "This script must be run from the main thread." buttons {"Cancel"} as critical
    error number -128
end if

on menuNeedsUpdate:(menu)

    my makeMenus()
end menuNeedsUpdate:

on makeMenus()

    newMenu's removeAllItems()

    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in someListInstances
        set this_item to item i of someListInstances
        set thisMenuItem to (current application's NSMenuItem's alloc()'s initWithTitle:this_item action:"someAction:" keyEquivalent:"")

        (newMenu's addItem:thisMenuItem)

        (thisMenuItem's setTarget:me) -- required for enabling the menu item
        if i is equal to 3 then
            (newMenu's addItem:(current application's NSMenuItem's separatorItem)) -- add a seperator
        end if
    end repeat

end makeMenus



on someAction:sender
    --MenuItem 
end someAction:

-- create an NSStatusBar
on makeStatusBar()
    set bar to current application's NSStatusBar's systemStatusBar

    set StatusItem to bar's statusItemWithLength:-1.0

    -- set up the initial NSStatusBars title
    StatusItem's setTitle:(theAccountNumberFromPlist & " " & thename & " " & fullEmail & " " & SNNumber & " " & appName)
    -- set up the initial NSMenu of the statusbar
    set newMenu to current application's NSMenu's alloc()'s initWithTitle:"Custom"

    newMenu's setDelegate:me (*


    *)

    StatusItem's setMenu:newMenu

end makeStatusBar


my makeStatusBar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of an idle handler.

```
on idle
-- do your stuff
return 5 -- idle handler will be executed again in 5 seconds.
end
```

Therefore you need to save your script as application. Here's the [essential part from apples docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html):

> **idle and quit Handlers for Stay-Open Applications**
>
> By default, a script application that receives a run or open command
> handles that single command and then quits. In contrast, a stay-open
> script application (one saved as Stay Open in Script Editor) stays
> open after it is launched.
>
> A stay-open script application can be useful for several reasons:
>
> - Stay-open script applications can receive and handle other commands in
>   addition to run and open. This allows you to use a script application
>   as a script server that, when it is running, provides a collection of
>   handlers that can be invoked by any other script.
> - Stay-open script applications can perform periodic actions, even in
>   the background, as long as the script application is running.
>
> Two particular handlers that stay-open script applications often
> provide are an idle handler and a quit handler.
>
> **idle Handlers**
>
> If a stay-open script application includes an idle handler,
> AppleScript sends the script application periodic idle commands—by
> default, every 30 seconds—allowing it to perform background tasks when
> it is not performing other actions.
>
> If an idle handler returns a positive number, that number becomes the
> rate (in seconds) at which the handler is called. If the handler
> returns a non-numeric value, the rate is not changed. You can return 0
> to maintain the default delay of 30 seconds.
>
> For example, when saved as a stay-open application, the following
> script beeps every 5 seconds:
>
> on idle
>     beep
>     return 5
> end idle
>
> The result returned from a handler is just the result of the last statement, even if it doesn’t include the word return explicitly.